# ruby on rails ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I'm using Rails 7.0.6, and Ruby 3.2.2. I have a local machine and a remote server. When I deploy with Capistrano by typing :

```
cap production deploy
```

I get this error :

```
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `bin/rails credentials:edit`
```

I was following this tutorial : [Deploy Ruby on Rails](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/20.04)

**Solutions I tried :**

-I added file name .rbenv-vars in the server app folder with those contents :

```
DATABASE_URL = postgresql://username:pass@127.0.0.1/myapp_production
SECRET_KEY_BASE = secret key here by typing in local machine "bundle exec rails secret"
```

but that didn't work.

-I also typed in terminal :

```
nano bin/rails credentials:edit
```

and then a file opened with this contents :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path("../config/application", __dir__)
require_relative "../config/boot"

require "rails/commands"
```

and I added this line :

```
secret_key_base = secret_key_here ******
```

but that didn't work either.Any solutions?

Comment: Did you try doing that the error suggested? `bin/rails credentials:edit` not `nano bin/rails credentials:edit`. If you want it to open with nano, use `EDITOR=nano bin/rails credentials:edit`

Comment: @SiimLiiser I just tried this in the local machine, and it didn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by didn't work? Did that command give an error? Did it just not do anything? Did it allow you to edit the credentials, but then deploy still failed with the same error?

Comment: @SiimLiiser I tried the command with EDITOR=nano as you said and it opened the secret key file, and then I added a new secret key that I generated with "bundle exec rails secret", but when I tried to deploy again, it gave me the same error. Am I suppose to run any other command after I edit that credential file before deploying?

Comment: After editing it, it created a diff right? Commit it before deploying as with any other change you want deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First generate the secret key :

```
rails secret
```

then type :

```
EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit --environment production
```

then paste the secret key there and type :

```
secret_key_base : key_here
```

then commit and push to github, and after that go to the server side and create this file :

```
nano .rbenv-vars
```

in app root folder, and add this info:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user_name:PASSWORD@127.0.0.1/app_name

RAILS_MASTER_KEY= you'll find the master key in local machine in "config/credentials/production.key

SECRET_KEY_BASE= same as the one you generated using "rails secret"
```

Answer (score 1):

master key in gitignore by default

create simlink and move masterkey to shared folder if you using capistrano